# What could cause a apex scheduled batch class to run but not update records even when unit tests have passed?

Tags: apex, scheduled-apex, custom-metadata

I spent hours troubleshooting my batch class but I cannot get it to update records. The ask is if a Opportunity *closeDate* >15th of the month, and *CareStatus__c = 'ADM','AAMT'* than *Ready_toCommitToStart__c* checkbox will be unchecked...There is also a custom metadata that is storing weekend dates that would need to be skipped if the 15th of the month is a weekend and move it to next business day.

My unit tests are passing which is what is confusing me...

**Batch class:**

```css
global class CAREforceSSEStatusBatch implements Database.Batchable<sObject> {
    public String query; 
    public Date fromDate = Date.today();
    private Date nextMonth = fromDate.addMonths(1); 
    public Date firstOfNextMonth = nextMonth.toStartOfMonth();
    private Set<String> caseListViewSet = new Set<String>{'ADMT', 'NEVR','AAMT'};
    private Date endOfNextMonth = nextMonth.addMonths(1).toStartOfMonth();
    private List<Date> observedDates;

    // Constructor
   /* global CAREforceSSEStatusBatch(String soql) {
        query = soql; // Initializing inside the constructor
        observedDates = getObservedDates();
    }*/ 

    // The batch job starts
    global Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext bc) {
        String soqlQuery = 'SELECT Id, Name, Ready_to_CommitToStart__c, CloseDate, CareStatus__c FROM Opportunity WHERE Ready_to_CommitToStart__c = true AND CloseDate >=: firstOfNextMonth';
        soqlQuery += ' AND CareStatus__c IN :caseListViewSet AND Is_SSE_Student__c = true AND RDS_Application_ID__c != NULL';
        System.debug('>>>> start ' + soqlQuery);
        return Database.getQueryLocator(soqlQuery);
    }

    global void execute(Database.BatchableContext bc, List<sObject> scope) {
        observedDates = getObservedDates();

        for (sObject record : scope) {
            Opportunity opp = (Opportunity)record;
            Date anticipatedStartDate = opp.CloseDate;
            String careStatus = opp.CareStatus__c   ;

            // Check if the Anticipated Start Date is >15th of the month
            if (anticipatedStartDate.day() > 15) {
                // Uncheck the Commit to Start checkbox
                opp.Ready_to_CommitToStart__c = false;
            }

            // Check if the Anticipated Start Date falls on an observed date
            if (observedDates.contains(anticipatedStartDate)) {
                // Extend the Commit to Start deadline until the following applicable business day
                opp.CloseDate = getNextBusinessDay(anticipatedStartDate);
            }
        }
        update scope; // Update the CARE profile records with the changes
    }

    global void finish(Database.BatchableContext bc) {
    }

    // Get the observed dates from custom metadata
    private List<Date> getObservedDates() {
        List<Date> dates = new List<Date>();
        for (SSE_Status_Cutoff_Dates__mdt cutoffDate : [SELECT id, Cutoff_Date__c FROM SSE_Status_Cutoff_Dates__mdt]) {
            dates.add(cutoffDate.Cutoff_Date__c);
        }
        return dates;
    }
                      

    // Get the next business day after the provided date
    private Date getNextBusinessDay(Date inputDate) {
        Date nextBusinessDay = inputDate;
        do {
            nextBusinessDay = nextBusinessDay.addDays(1);
        } while (nextBusinessDay.day() == 1 || nextBusinessDay.day() == 7 || observedDates.contains(nextBusinessDay));
        return nextBusinessDay;
    }
}
```

**Test class:**

```css
@isTest
public class CAREforceSSEStatusBatchTest {

    @TestSetup
    static void setupData(){
        // Arrange
        Contact testContact = new Contact(FirstName = 'Test', LastName = 'Contact');
        insert testContact;
        
        Date closeDate = Date.today().addMonths(1).addDays(16);
        Opportunity testOpportunity = new Opportunity(
            Ready_to_CommitToStart__c = true,
            Name = 'Test Name ASD15',
            StudentContact__c = testContact.Id,
            StageName = 'Prospect',
            CloseDate = closeDate,
            CareStatus__c = 'AAMT',
            Is_SSE_Student__c = true,
            RDS_Application_ID__c = '2314546515'
        );

        insert testOpportunity;
        
        Date closeDate2 = Date.newInstance(2024, 4, 15);
        Opportunity testOpportunity2 = new Opportunity(
            Ready_to_CommitToStart__c = true,
            Name = 'Test Name ASDMetadata',
            StudentContact__c = testContact.Id,
            StageName = 'Prospect',
            CloseDate = closeDate2,
            CareStatus__c = 'ADMT',
            Is_SSE_Student__c = true,
            RDS_Application_ID__c = '23145465156'
        );

        insert testOpportunity2;
    }
    
    @isTest
    private static void testOpportunityASD15() {        
        
        Test.startTest();
        String query = 'SELECT Id, Name, Ready_to_CommitToStart__c FROM Opportunity LIMIT 1';
        CAREforceSSEStatusBatch batch = new CAREforceSSEStatusBatch();
        Database.executeBatch(batch);
        Test.stopTest();
        
        // Assert - Add assertions if necessary
        List<Opportunity> lstOpps = [SELECT Id, Ready_to_CommitToStart__c FROM Opportunity WHERE Name = 'Test Name ASD15'];
        Assert.areNotEqual(false, lstOpps[0].Ready_to_CommitToStart__c, 'Commit to Start changed' );
    }
    
    @isTest
    private static void testOpportunityASDMetadata() {        
        Date closeDate2 = Date.newInstance(2024, 4, 15);

        Test.startTest();
        String query = 'SELECT Id, Name, Ready_to_CommitToStart__c FROM Opportunity LIMIT 1';
        CAREforceSSEStatusBatch batch = new CAREforceSSEStatusBatch();
        Database.executeBatch(batch);
        Test.stopTest();
        
        // Assert - Add assertions if necessary
        List<Opportunity> lstOpps = [SELECT Id, CloseDate FROM Opportunity WHERE Name = 'Test Name ASDMetadata'];
        Assert.areNotEqual(closeDate2, lstOpps[0].CloseDate, 'The Closed Date changed' );
    }

    @isTest
    private static void testScheduledBatchExecution() {
        // Schedule the batch job
        Test.StartTest();
        CAREforceSSEStatusBatchSchedulable scheduledBatch = new CAREforceSSEStatusBatchSchedulable();
        String scheduleExpression = '0 0 23 * * ?'; // Run daily at 11:00 PM
        System.schedule('Test status Check', scheduleExpression, scheduledBatch);
        Test.stopTest();
        
        // Assert - Verify if the batch job is scheduled correctly
    }
}
```

**Batch job schedule:**

```css
global class CAREforceSSEStatusBatchSchedulable implements Schedulable {
    
    // Execute at regular intervals
    global void execute(SchedulableContext ctx){
      CAREforceSSEStatusBatch batch = new CAREforceSSEStatusBatch();
      Database.executebatch(batch, 200);  
    }
}
```

**Execute Anonymous code to schedule job:**

```css
System.schedule('Run Test Job skip date mohamed', '0 35 22 * * ?', new CAREforceSSEStatusBatchSchedulable());
```

Comment: analyzing the debug log for the start() and execute() method will be instructive. Does the execute() get invoked?  Note that in your testmethod, the `String query =` line does nothing and can be removed.  You can also make the execute() signature be `List<Opportunity> scope` and avoid the cast

Comment: I'm not seeing anything in my debug logs...

Comment: there will be a debug log for the start() method, 1..n debug logs for each `execute()`, and a debug log for the `finish()`